# How to replace symbol in multiplefiles?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 13.04, rename, filename

I have many files in directory(with folders so i think solution must be recursive in deep)

- root-folder

  - file-1.png
  - file-2.png
  - file-3.png
  - file-4.png
  - file-5.png
  - folder-1

    - file-1.png
    - file-2.png
    - file-3.png

I need to rename all files, which contains `-` character to `_`.

```
file-1.png -> file_1.png
```

But. I have little remark. `folder-1` and `root-folder` must be not affected.

How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using find and the perl rename command:

```
find . -depth -name "*-*" -execdir prename -v s/-/_/g {} +
```

Answer (score -1):

You do something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

ROOT_DIR=$1

cd "$ROOT_DIR"
IFS="
"
for file in $(find -type f)
do
    mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -e 's#-#_#g')"
done
unset IFS
cd -
```

Assuming this script is called "my-rename.sh". Call it like this:

```
$ ./my-rename.sh <path-to-root-folder>
```

The only trick to using this script is that if any parent directory has "-" in their name, you'll change that too. You can certainly handle that but the answer would become too complex and the real solution lost in the middle of it.

Does this do the trick? Let me know if you have any other questions.

Cheers!

Comment: See [Pitfall 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1)

Comment: @Luiz, To work-around the "rename parent directory before renaming files in that directory" is to use `find ... -depth ...`. But as geirha points out, using a `for` loop is wrong here. You want something like: `find . -depth -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d "" path; do file=$(basename "$path"); if [[ $file == *-* ]]; then ( cd "$(dirname "$path")" && mv "$file" "${file//-/_}"); fi; done`